# Transfering Rows Between DataGridViews Across 2 Different Forms In VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview, transfer

first time posting.
So I'm making this program in visual studio 2013 in VB.NET

Lets say I have 2 forms:

Form1 and Form2 and on Form1 I have DataGridView1 and on form 2 I have DataGridView2

Both data grids have the same columns.

How can I on the click event of a button on Form1 Get all the data from DataGridView1 from the row i'm currently focused/selected on to be transferred into DataGridView2 on Form2.

**Image of what i'm trying to do.**
[image]

If anyone can help me out with this one it would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the reply's but I ended up doing this:

```
Private Sub searchPartsDataGridView_CellContentClicked(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles searchPartsDataGridView.CellContentDoubleClick
    Dim colName As String = searchPartsDataGridView.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name()
    Dim rowIndex = searchPartsDataGridView.CurrentRow.Index
    If colName = "ITEMNO" Then
        formPartsRequest.partsRequestItemsDataGridView.Rows.Add(searchPartsDataGridView.Rows(rowIndex).Cells("ITEMNO").Value, searchPartsDataGridView.Rows(rowIndex).Cells("DESC").Value)
    End If
End Sub
```

Not sure if this is the best way to do it or if its good coding practice but It seem's to work fine and it suit's my purposes. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
'Form1-- following code will be placed in button click
Dim cells(grd.Columns.Count) As New Object
For c As int = 0 To grd.Columns.Count
    cells(c) = grd.CurrentRow.Cells(c).Value
Next
Dim frm As Form1 = Application.OpenForms("frmName")
frm.sendRow(cells)


'Form2 -- Create a method that will add all cell values from form 1
Public Sub sendRow(ByVal cells() As Object)
    grd.Rows.Add(cells)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

First we really have to know you are using databound DataGridView or not.

#### If DataBound:

**Form1:**

```
dim dt as new DataTable()

// Fetch data from DB and assign it to DataSource.
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    // Run query to fetch data
    // dt = GetTableByRunningQuery    

    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt

End Sub

Private Sub btnTransfer_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim frm2 as new Form2()
        frm2.dataSource = dt
        frm2.Show()
End Sub
```

**Form2:**

```
Public dataSource as Object
Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSource

End Sub
```

#### If NOT DataBound:

**Form1:**

```
Private Sub btnTransfer_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim frm2 as new Form2()
        frm2.SetRows(dataGridView1.Rows)
        frm2.Show()
End Sub
```

**Form2:**

```
Public Sub SetRows(ByVal rows as DataGridViewRowCollection)
   For each row as DataGridViewRow in rows
      Dim newRow as DataGridViewRow = Ctype(row.Clone(), DataGridViewRow)
      dataGridView1.Rows.Add(newRow)
   Next
End Sub
```